# Run Script as admin ignore prompt

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

While calling the below script from VBScript it's prompting me sceen. can this be ignored?

```
objShell.ShellExecute "C:\batchScript.cmd", MyPath, "", "runas", 1
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the batchScript.cmd into a subfolder of your drive rather than the root? Sometimes the root can cause problems when trying to run executables. Try C:\batch\batchScript.cmd instead, after making the batch directory.

Comment: Or tried using objShell.Run instead? Although, I think the file location is the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a scheduled task to run with highest privileges, you can disable UAC prompting for admin accounts, or you can disable UAC entirely. Either way the user running the script must have administrative privileges (meaning you could just as well run the the batch script directly without the "runas" workaround).